# Which is the right way to link images and export in Eclipse (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, export

The problem I'm having right now has to do with how images are linked when exporting the jar. Right now, my program runs on eclipse and the images do work, but when I try to run it from the exported file, the screen goes white. I have the images in a src/res folder and they appear inside the jar just free in the root directory. the code which I use to link the images is this one:

```
img = ImageIO.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                "\\bkg.png"));
```

My question is, how should I write the path so I can export the jar and get the images to work? Or which line of code should I use to make it work?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
img = ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
```

Doing this, you have to know that `path` is a local path starting from the package of MyClass.

Comment: MyClass being the name of the class of the method that loads the image or "MyClass" like that?

Comment: Most often it is indeed the name of the class loading the image, but not necessarily. Just chose MyClass conviniently so that the path is easy to write. For example, if a class is in a package that contains a folder `data` where is stored the image, it might be convenient to use this class because the local path to the image is simple :  `data/img.png`.

Comment: I solve it using this:
img =ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/res/g3.png"));

The images were moved in a package named res.